# How to detect when user changes Stack frame while debugging in a VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I’m writing an extension for visual studio code, where I animate some parts of the debugging process. For this extension I want to detect if the user has changed the stack frame viewed with the debug side bar. Is it possible to get an event that indicates that the user has switched the stack frame?

So far, I tried to solve this problem with a DebugAdapterTracker but it seems that there is no event that indicates this.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
await vscode.debug.onDidChangeActiveDebugSession(e => {
  console.log('CHANGE ACTIVE', e.id);
})
```

It is fired when the user changes the active session from the debug toolbar or via the call stack frames.

It does also fire on the first debug session starting (since that does change the active debug session) and when the user closes one debug session and that makes another session become active.  So you will have to work around those situations.

`onDidTerminateDebugSession` and `onDidStartDebugSession` would fire in those two situations but I am not sure about the order.

So you could not create the `onDidChangeActiveDebugSession` listener until one debug session has been started for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I implemented it by adding your code directly in the activate function in the Extension.ts file. But it seems that it only fires once when I start the debug session and not when I change the stack frame.

Comment: It works every time I change the stack frame for me.  Did you put a breakpoint on the `console.log()` line to check?  And how are you changing the stack frame?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get this information for now (as of 15/03/2022).

It's an open issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63943.
Current status is: waiting for API Proposal. You can contribute there, if you like.